# using numpy fromfunction to fill a matrix with a custom function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ufunc

This is related to [another question I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588624/vectorizing-a-double-for-loop) except there I am looking for a vectorized/broadcasting solution.

Here I am hoping to try using `np.fromfunction` but am having issues.

### The MWE is

```
# L1 and L2 will range from 0 to 3 typically, sometimes up to 5
# all of the following are dummy values but match correct `type`
L1, L2, x1, x2, fac = 2, 3, 2.0, 4.5, 2.3
saved_values = np.random.uniform(high=75.0, size=[max(L1,L2) + 1, max(L1,L2) + 1]) 
facts = np.random.uniform(high=65.0, size=[L1 + L2 + 1])
val = 0

for i in range(L1+1):
    sf = saved_values[L1][i] * x1 ** (L1 - i)
    for j in range(L2 + 1):
        m = i + j
        if m % 2 == 0:
            num = sf * facts[m] / (2 * fac) ** (m / 2)
            val += saved_values[L2][j] * x1 ** (L1 - j) * num
```

rather than use a double for loop, which is not vectorized and potentially slower (being vectorized is more important for me), I would like to use `np.fromfunction` to fill a matrix with the necessary values

### I tried the following

```
matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j:
                         saved_values[L1][i] * x1 ** (L1 - i) *
                         saved_values[L2][j] * x2 ** (L2 - j) *
                         facts[i+j] / (2 * fac) **( (i+j) / 2),
                         (L1+1,L2+1)
                         )
```

This generates the double for loop matrix, I then need to go over it and make anything that would fail `(i+j) % 2 == 0` have a zero value, and then sum all elements in the matrix.

### However

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                 
  File "main.py", line 54, in <module>                                                                                                                                             
    (L1+1,L2+1)                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1808, in fromfunction                                                                                          
    return function(*args,**kwargs)                                                                                                                                                
  File "main.py", line 53, in <lambda>                                                                                                                                             
    facts[i+j] / (2 * fac) **( (i+j) / 2),                                                                                                                                         
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: `fromfunction` does not 'vectorize'.  When you have problems like this, write a small function that shows you what the `i,j` actually are.

Answer (score 3):

As I suppose, you think that the function passed as the first parameter
to *np.fromfunction* is called **several** times, for each combination
of *i* and *j*.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. To see the **actual** way how
it operates, make such experiment:

```
def myFun(i, j):
    print(f'myFun:\n{i.shape}\n{i}\n{j.shape}\n{j}')
    rv = i + j
    return rv
```

I deliberately put a trace printout, to show what I mean.

Then run it:

```
np.fromfunction(myFun, (2, 3))
```

The result is:

```
myFun:
(2, 3)
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
(2, 3)
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 1. 2.]]

array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [1., 2., 3.]])
```

The first part is the printout, occuring **only once** and the second - the
actual result. Note that:

- shapes of both  *i* and *j* are *(2,3)*,
- both *i* and *j* are actually **arrays**, not integers,
- the whole computation is performed by addition of both arrays.

So the conclusions are that:

- the passed function operates in a **vectorized** way,
  on **arrays of parameters**, adding respective elements and
  returning the result,
- your concept is probably impossible to implement.

Comment: can't I just make an arbitrary myfunc that depends on i,j, and also an array whose indice uses the i, j, and do that?

Comment: Yes, you can. But this function must be invoked in 2 nested loops, not using *np.fromfunction*.

Comment: I can't use loops. Everything here is scalar, but the real problem is vectors. I am trying to get rid of the `for loops` so that I have a vectorized solution that can be passed arrays. i.e., `m % 2 == 0` breaks vectorization, as does the for loops themselves since they have `range(L1+1)` etc. i.e., I need to evaluate that loop passing the `x` and `y` and `z` components of vectors. It is currently set up for only 1 dimension to be passed.