# The behavior of numpy.fromfunction()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, function

I was trying to create different arrays using Numpy's `fromfunction()`. It was working fine until I faced this issue. I tried to make an array of ones using `fromfunction()`(I know I can create it using `ones()` and `full()`) and here is the issue :

```
array = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 1, shape=(2, 2), dtype=float)
print(array)
```

Surprisingly, the output of this function is this :

```
1
```

Which is expected to be :

```
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

When I change the input function by adding zero times `i`, It works just fine.

```
array = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i*0 + 1, shape=(2, 2), dtype=float)
print(array)
```

The output of this code is :

```
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

My main question is how does `fromfunction()` actually behaves? I passed the same function with 2 different representations and the output is completely different.

Comment: Check the documentation, particularly what it says about how `function` is used. *"Each parameter represents the coordinates of the array varying along a specific axis. For example, if shape were `(2, 2)`, then the parameters would be `array([[0, 0], [1, 1]])` and `array([[0, 1], [0, 1]])`"* https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html

Comment: A common misconception (I don't mean to be derogatory, I myself used to have this misconception) is that your function receives each scalar value of `i` and `j` in turn. It doesn't: it's called exactly once, and it receives `i` and `j` as arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using numpy fromfunction to fill a matrix with a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590749/using-numpy-fromfunction-to-fill-a-matrix-with-a-custom-function)

Comment: @slothrop Thanks for your comment, Now I get it. It doesn't run the function on each i,j separately.

Comment: is `i,j` referring to specified axis?

Comment: `i` is the array such that `i[r][c]==r` and `j` is the array such that `j[r][c]==c`.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. `array([[0, 0], [1, 1]])` refers to `i` values and `array([[0, 1], [0, 1]])` refers to `j` values.. I completely understood How it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callable function is passed two arrays, not repeatedly called with two numbers:

```
i=[ [ 0.0, 0.0 ],
    [ 1.0, 1.0 ] ]

j=[ [ 0.0, 1.0 ],
    [ 0.0, 1.0 ] ]
```

It returns what it is asked to provide ... just ONCE ... to be the ultimate result of np.fromfunction.

So an input of 1 returns just 1
whereas an input of i*0+1 returns

```
[ [ 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 1.0, 1.0 ] ] * 0 + 1
```

which is the (broadcast) array

```
[ [ 1.0, 1.0 ],
  [ 1.0, 1.0 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of the function

```
numpy.fromfunction(function, shape, *, dtype=<class 'float'>, like=None, **kwargs)
```

function : callable

> The function is called with N parameters, where N is the rank of shape. **Each parameter represents the coordinates of the array varying along a specific axis**. For example, if shape were (2, 2), then the parameters would be array([[0, 0], [1, 1]]) and array([[0, 1], [0, 1]])

shape(N,) : tuple of ints

> Shape of the output array, which also determines the shape of the coordinate arrays passed to function.

Returns: fromfunction : any

> The result of the call to function is passed back directly. Therefore the **shape of fromfunction is completely determined by function. If function returns a scalar value, the shape of fromfunction would not match the shape parameter**.

emphasis is mine.

Document: **https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html#numpy-fromfunction**

Answer (score 1):

NumPy's `fromfunction()` actually behaves just as `function(*np.indices(shape))` in this case.

`np.indices` returns an array that you can multiply and add with numbers. When you multiply `*np.indices((2, 2))` by 0 you get an array of zeroes and then +1 increases all elements by one but without the multiplication result is just the scalar 1.

By coincidence `i` is 2*2 array and `j` is an array of the same shape but with different numbers but lambda `i*0+1` uses only `i`.